# PhpStorm removes whitespaces on its own

Tags: phpstorm

**Problem Description:**

*I change something in my code, but PhpStorm removes all the unnecessary whitespaces at the end from several lines, where i havent worked on.*

**What i tried:**

*In Preferences > Editor > General, i deactivated the Option "Remove trailing spaces on:…" in the "On Save" Section*

**Result**: *not worked. PhpStorm still removes unnecessary whitespaces*

Does someone know, how to fix that?

Comment: If they are unnecessary, why do you want to fix it? ;-)

Comment: @axiac, because when I check in the files with git, all lines where PhpStorm removed spaces are listed. But that's not supposed to be the case. The other lines should stay as they are.

Comment: 1) Check your `.editorconfig` file -- settings from there will overwrite the IDE settings (the nature of such files). 2) Could be done by some File Watcher if you have them ofc (e.g. CS_Fixer that you may be running on Save etc.)

Comment: @Eugene So, did you managed to resolve your issue? If you did -- was it the setting from the `.editorconfig` file?