# PhpStorm is doing something with blank lines so that they are shown as changes in my commits

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, blank-line

Basically after changing files in PhpStorm and commiting I get a lot of these blank line changes but I haven't touched any of them.

[image]

I turned on "keep indent on empty lines" and turned off "remove trailing spaces" but it didn't fix the problem.

What's going on here? For now I have to stage lines instead of whole files to avoid pushing garbage changes but that's less than ideal.

Comment: 1) See my comment in https://stackoverflow.com/q/69989913/783119 -- do you have that? 2) So what changes there exactly? If you enable showing whitespace symbols -- will you see removed space/tab symbols there? (I do not think that a mixed line ending will be show here after normalizing)

Comment: @LazyOne doing trim_trailing_whitespace = false seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> I turned on "keep indent on empty lines" and turned off "remove trailing spaces" but it didn't fix the problem.

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Remove trailing spaces on:` is indeed the option that controls such behaviour. As per your description you already have that disabled.

If you have `.editorconfig` files in your project then corresponding setting from there (`trim_trailing_whitespace`) will overwrite corresponding IDE settings. It is expected as it's the whole nature of such files.

In this case you have a few options here:

- either edit your `.editorconfig` file accordingly (https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#trim_trailing_whitespace)
- or disable such support in the IDE (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Enable EditorConfig support`)

  [image]
- or even more radical one: disable EditorConfig plugin completely (which affects the whole IDE: all projects / code styles).